# Message: Element <div id="tabber_obj_0_div_3" class="ptr"> could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I 'm trying to scrape reviews for books from the given url. I need the book name and each review in separate rows. Following is my code. I'm using both selenium and bs4. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated and sincere apologies if I'm not adhering to the post guidelines as I'm relatively new to this portal!

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
browser = Firefox()
url ="https://www.booksaremagic.net/?q=h.tviewer&using_sb=status"
browser.get(url)
detailed_list = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title='Detailed']")
detailed_list.click()

books1 = []
for i in range(1,201):
    page_source1 = browser.page_source
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page_source1, "html.parser")
    for book1 in soup1.find_all('td',{"nbr ca"}):
        browser.find_element_by_tag_name('a[class="lightgrey bordered button moreinfo togsrus"]').click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabber_obj_0_div_3']").click()
        reviews = browser.find_element_by_id('tabber_obj_0_divbody_3').text
        all_books_scraped1 = [reviews]
        books1.append(all_books_scraped1)
        print("Finished Extracting Page:",i)
    try:
        select = Select(browser.find_element_by_class_name('quicknav')) 
        select.select_by_value(str(i))
    except:
        print("\nScraping Complete...")
```

Output should be df with:

(Cols)Books  Review
(Rows)Book1  Review 1
Book1  Review 2
Book1  Review N
.
.
.
Book9918 Review N

Answer (score 0):

I found that the website some kind of API to get the data, here's my code:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

link = 'https://www.booksaremagic.net/?q=h.tviewer&using_sb=status&filt[status]=%20activenotcb%2C__instock&infscroll=1&&t=3&lim=500&dm=7&using_sb=status&overridelim=1&dm=7&offs=0'

# Get 500 books at once, if you're planning to get more, add 500 to the offs, so it goes like 0, 500, 1000, 1500, ...
# You can use up to 10000 at once, so 0, 10000, 20000, ...
res = r.get(link)
data = res.json()
books_5 = data["rs"]
# Each row in books_5 will contain html with 5 books in it
for row in books_5:
    for x in row.values():
        soup = BeautifulSoup(x, "html.parser")
        # Get the title
        title = soup.find_all('b')[0].text
        # get the link for the book
        link_book = soup.find_all('a')[0]["href"]
        # get the html page for the requested book
        res = r.get("https://www.booksaremagic.net/"+link_book+"&t=3")
        data = res.json()
        try:
            all_reviews_html = data["rs"][0]["sr"]["iv"]["rs"][0]["tabdata"][3]["tab_body"]
            soup_text = BeautifulSoup(all_reviews_html, "html.parser").text
            reviews = re.findall("“[^”]+”[^“]+", soup_text)
            # start and ends with " and the other is what follows after this —
            print(reviews)
        except:
            print(title, ": has no reviews.")
            pass
        # Here you have the title and all_reviews in html format for the book, extract your reviews with beautifulsoup
        # add your treatement here
```

You just need to extract the reviews from the html code `all_reviews_html`, it only has the reviews in it, not the full page. And you have the `title`. Just add after that the printing.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you got the all_reviews_html?
I did this after that:
`code`
books1 = []
# add your treatement here
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(all_reviews_html, 'html.parser')
        reviews = soup1.text
        all_books_scraped1 = [title,reviews]
        books1.append(all_books_scraped1)
`code`
 but it says : all_reviews_html = data["rs"][0]["sr"]["iv"]["rs"][0]["tabdata"][3]["tab_body"] error, IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It works when I run outside the loop, apologies if I'm missing on something simple!

Comment: Hey, I apparently missed something in my end. I edited the code, the error happened because there are books that don't have any reviews, in my code I didn't put this in mind. Now it's fixed.

Comment: thank you so much. Is there a way to separate the reviews for each book? Right now, I'm getting a review column with all reviews clustered together in a single row. Anyways I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I edited the code again, I added some kind of regex, it doesn't work perfectly yet, but I hope you'll find something to do with it.